# Ruby on Rails - Adding photo to unsaved model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got polymorphic model which is storing data about photos. I am using that model to many types of content, for example users photos (content_type: User, content_id: user_id), games screen-shots etc. Till now I was using that Photo model only to already existing contents. Now I need to add some photos to certain model at creation stage.

Problem is, that I cannot pass content_id to partial because model doesn't has it before saving it.

Below please find code which is working for existing models.

Code of `photos/add_photo` partial:

```
    <% form_for(@photo, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_messages %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :attachable_id, :value => content.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :attachable_type, :value => content.class.name %>
        file inputs goes here...
        <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
    <% end %>
```

And here how I pass example variables to partial in Game view:

```
    <%= render :partial => 'photos/add_photo', :locals => { :content => @game } %>
```

Now I want let users add screenshots to newly created report. I've got controller:

```
    def new
      @raport = Raport.new
    end
```

How I can force model to reserve or generate ID? Maybe I should figure out another solution and change whole code?

Answer (score 0):

I would use ajax to save the photo with a random token hash, and then have the ajax response update a hidden field in the the new object form with that token hash.  Then when you save the new object have a callback find the photo by token and update the attachable id & type fields.